# USDA soil classification vs FAO/UNESCO soil classification

Tags: soil, soil-science

I am making a global social media website for farmers and gardeners which can be used to share information about plant varieties. This sharing is done via so called garden journals.
In a garden journal different things related to growth and crop performance can be recorded such as the sow date, the time it took until the seeds germinated or the plant flowered and when the first moment of harvest was. The author of the garden journal can also record the bugs, diseases and animals that interacted with the plant(s).

I would like people from different places in the world to use the garden journals of people who share the same soiltype as them. In order to make the search for these garden journals more easy i want to use a soil classification system. When starting a garden journal the author can enter the soiltype of the ground he or she will be growing the plants on. When the garden journal is finished other people who share the same soiltype can easily find this journal by performing a search based on that particular soiltype.

There are two major soiltype classifications in the world, namely the one from USDA which has 12 major soiltypes and the one from FAO/UNESCO which consists of far more different soiltypes.

I would like to hear your opinion about which of the two systems would be the best for my usecase. I would also like to know if the data of any of these 2 systems is accessible via an API. In other words, is there a website that allows me to find the soiltype of a  country, province or city/village via an API call?